# Alternative for `some` method in NodeList

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question, what simplest method do you know to replace the method `some` for NodeList? This `some` method is only for Array prototype.

I have currently come up with the rather outlandish idea of iterating and holding a boolean in a variable, however I would like to know your point of view.

My obscure approach

```js
const toCheck = (elem) => elem.checked;

const methodSome = (list, fn) => {
  let result = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (fn(list[i])) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="something"]`);

const hasBeenChecked = methodSome(elems, toCheck);
```

Comment: `[...NodeList]` problem solved use `.some()` all you want.

Comment: Is it working? Then this question is off topic here and better suited at https://codereview.stackoverflow.com. Otherwise

Comment: The easier approach would be to change the "array-like" node list into an actual array. Maybe `Array.from(nodelist)` or `[...nodelist]`. That way you can use all of the array methods without having to polyfill them yourself.

Comment: ok thanks @derpirscher - learning new exchanges every day :)

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the spread operator can put elements into an array.

A simpler approach is to use the [`:checked` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) with a call to `document.querySelector()` (instead of using `document.querySelectorAll()`). The [Double NOT operator `!!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!) can be used to convert the element to a boolean.

```
const hasBeenChecked = !!(document.querySelector(`[name="something"]:checked`));
```

With this approach there is no need to put elements into an array and have a function with a loop to check those elements.

See an example here:

```js
const hasBeenChecked = !!(document.querySelector(`[name="something"]:checked`));
console.log('hasBeenChecked: ', hasBeenChecked);
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" name="something" /> something?</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="something" checked /> something?</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="something" /> something?</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="something" checked /> something?</div>
```

Comment: And there’s no need to use `querySelectorAll` at that point: `!!document.querySelector('[name="something"]:checked')`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert a NodeList to an Array

```js
const hasBeenChecked = [...elems].some(toCheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an array first:

With spread operator:

```js
const toCheck = (elem) => elem.checked;

const methodSome = (list, fn) => {
  let result = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (fn(list[i])) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="something"]`);

const hasBeenChecked = [...elems].some(toCheck);
```

With `Array.from`

```js
const toCheck = (elem) => elem.checked;

const methodSome = (list, fn) => {
  let result = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (fn(list[i])) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="something"]`);

const hasBeenChecked = Array.from(elems).some(toCheck);
```